# Disable clang-tidy analysis for packages imported via CPMAddPackage

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project using CMake, I have enabled clang-tidy via

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY ${CLANG_TIDY_EXE} -warnings-as-errors=${CLANG_TIDY_SETTINGS} -checks=${CLANG_TIDY_SETTINGS})
```

This works just fine but there is a target imported via CPM

```
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME mosquittolib
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY eclipse/mosquitto
        VERSION 2.0.11
        OPTIONS
          "WITH_CJSON OFF"
          "DOCUMENTATION OFF"
)
```

that fails my entire project indeed some clang-tidy checks are not happy about mosquitto code.

I have tried to disable clang-tidy analysis in different ways:

```
    set_target_properties(mosquitto PROPERTIES CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "")
    set_target_properties(libmosquitto PROPERTIES CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "")
    set_target_properties(mosquitto_pub PROPERTIES CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "")
    set_target_properties(mosquitto_sub PROPERTIES CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "")
    set_target_properties(mosquitto_rr PROPERTIES CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "")
```

or with:

```
    set_property(TARGET mosquitto PROPERTY SYSTEM TRUE)
    set_property(TARGET libmosquitto PROPERTY SYSTEM TRUE)
    set_property(TARGET mosquitto_pub PROPERTY SYSTEM TRUE)
    set_property(TARGET mosquitto_sub PROPERTY SYSTEM TRUE)
    set_property(TARGET mosquitto_rr PROPERTY SYSTEM TRUE)
```

no luck so far. I'm using CMake 3.27.7

Is there any other way to disable clang-tidy analysis when compiling the source for a given target?

Comment: I think set_target_properties should be like this: `set_target_properties(mosquitto PROPERTIES CXX_CLANG_TIDY "")`  without the `CMAKE_` part

Comment: @user20716902 I have tried that as well

Comment: Generally you want to `set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY` _after_ importing the 3rd party projects but _before_ your own. In my own setup, I've factored out clang tidy setup and various other setups so I can fine-tune. (Also set header filter option to clang tidy worth a look if you haven't already.)